# How to recover second element separate by character with index equiv

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a table in Excel like this:

[image]

I used index with double equiv to have only the price for column A, the price for column B, the price for column C, I did this :

```
=INDEX($J$1:$L$4;EQUIV($F6;$J$1:$J$4;0);EQUIV(Z$24;$J$1:$L$1;0))
```

But I would like to have only the value at the right of ";"  but I don't know how to combine with my index and equiv to have only the value  `111,1456,44455.`

I have this:

[image]

Comment: is your Price column a combination of two other columns and you want only the right side? **or** you combine two columns as a price and then you want to separate and use the right side?

Comment: I would get the price alone in a helper column using mid(0 with find() and find the ";"

Comment: I want only right side of price with using index equiv

Comment: right side after the ";"

Comment: MID() you tell it where to start, which is why I suggested find() for you. It may be worth you trying it.

Comment: Something like: MID(A1,FIND(";",A1,1)+1,20)

Answer (score 1):

`EQUIV()` is the french name for `MATCH()` am I right?

If so just use a wildcard-match:

```
=MATCH("*;"&$F6,$J$1:$J$4,0)
```

Or the french equivalent:

```
=EQUIV("*;"&F6;$J$1:$J$4;0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear, I am assuming you have a **multiple values** separated by **semicolon** ";" in column Price and now you want a portion of it, in this case only **Right**, if that is so, here is your solution:

Price

112233;50.99

223344;15.50

3344;150.5

to get the **left side**, use

```
=LEFT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND(";",C2)-1)
```

here you have to subtract -1 because we don't want to include the semicolon at the end

to get the **right side**, use

```
=RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-FIND(";",C2))
```

**Result:**

[image: My Result]